# Getting "ieframe.dll failed to register" while installing an application built using watin?

Tags: c#, watin

Recently I have developed an automation application using WatiN API, in .NET Framework 3.5, for automation of an AD posting process. But at the time of installation i get an error that states this,

"Module C:\Program Files\XYZ Solution\XYZ App\ieframe.dll Failed to register.
HRESULT -2147467263. Contact your support personnel."

I am using IE browser to automate the whole process. The project has been developed in Win XP, VS 2008, .NET Framework 3.5, using Watin API ver-2.1.0.1196, in C#.

The thing is that it works fine although it shows the error, but my client does not wants to get the error.

Can anybody please help me with this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following MSDN post touches on your issue specifically.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/c0b61b07-6255-4ede-b6b0-c7c6609b6a41/

Please let me know if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks GraehamF, for your help, I found out that there is no need of registering the ieframe.dll while using Windows XP SP-3 or Windows 7 or Windows Vista, as there is no need to register the dll file, as .NET Framework takes care of that. So we can add the dll, but no need to register it. Sorry for late reply. Once again thanks for you help. :)